# How to get Array[Seq[String]] from DataFrame?

Tags: scala, dataframe

How to pass `DataFrame` `cc` into `Array[Seq[String]]`?

```
val factors = $(ccCols).split(",")
val cc = dataset.select(factors.head, factors.tail: _*)
```

I tried this way, but it gives me `Array[Row]`:

```
cc.rdd.collect()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to use the `toSeq` function of the `Row` object:

```
val a = sc.parallelize(Seq((1,2),(3,4))).toDF("a", "b")
a.show
/*
Output:
+-+-+
|a|b|
+-+-+
|1|2|
|3|4|
+-+-+
*/

a.collect.map(_.toSeq)
// Output: Array(WrappedArray(1, 2), WrappedArray(3, 4))
```

Comment: It's now Array[Seq[Ahy]]. How to substitute Any by String?

Comment: I think a `a.collect.map(_.toSeq.map(_.toString))` would do it