# Convert spark dataframe to sequence of sequences and vice versa in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a `DataFrame` and I want to convert it into a sequence of sequences and vice versa.
Now the thing is, I want to do it dynamically, and write something which runs for `DataFrame` with any number/type of columns.
In summary, these are the questions:

1. How to convert `Seq[Seq[String]]` to a `DataFrame`?
2. How to convert `DataFrame` to `Seq[Seq[String]`?
3. How to perform 2 but also make the `DataFrame` infer the schema and decide column types by itself?

**UPDATE 1** 
This is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37328384/how-to-get-arrayseqstring-from-dataframe) question because in answer to that question solution provided is not dynamic, it works for two columns or how many columns is to be hardcoded. I am trying to find a dynamic solution.

Comment: If you want to convert the dataframe to `Seq[Seq[String]` to perform some operations it is most likely easier to do them directly on the dataframe.

Comment: I mainly want to do 2, but knowing how to do 1 will be good too as I MIGHT need to do it too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Array\[Seq\[String\]\] from DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37328384/how-to-get-arrayseqstring-from-dataframe). The answer in this question gives you `Array[Seq[String]]` (see comment under answer), to convert to `Seq` simply do `.toSeq`.

Comment: @Shaido as I wrote, `I want to do it dynamically`. I can not specify the number of columns. Looking for a generic solution. Also updated the question.

Comment: That solution should work for any number of columns, you can try it out.

Comment: Umm, what I mean to say is I don't know how many columns there are and what their names are how am I supposed to write `.toDF("a", "b")` dynamically?

Comment: You already have a dataframe. `.toDF("a", "b")` is only used in the answer to create a test dataframe. What you want is the `.collect.map(_.toSeq.map(_.toString))` part.

Comment: @saadi you can use `toDF(columnNameList: _*)`. previously you have to initialise the list with the column names you want (which could be `List("v1", "v2", ..., "vn")`). But I am not sure that will correctly infer data types...

Comment: You can argue that it's not a duplicate. It is for me. You also don't show any efforts into solving your problems besides asking the question. Thus I'm closing the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you can dynamically create a dataframe from `Seq[Seq[String]]`:

```
scala> val seqOfSeq = Seq(Seq("a","b", "c"),Seq("3","4", "5"))
seqOfSeq: Seq[Seq[String]] = List(List(a, b, c), List(3, 4, 5))

scala> val lengthOfRow = seqOfSeq(0).size
lengthOfRow: Int = 3

scala> val tempDf = sc.parallelize(seqOfSeq).toDF
tempDf: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: array<string>]

scala> val requiredDf = tempDf.select((0 until lengthOfRow).map(i => col("value")(i).alias(s"col$i")): _*)
requiredDf: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [col0: string, col1: string ... 1 more field]

scala> requiredDf.show
+----+----+----+
|col0|col1|col2|
+----+----+----+
|   a|   b|   c|
|   3|   4|   5|
+----+----+----+
```

How to convert DataFrame to `Seq[Seq[String]`:

```
val newSeqOfSeq = requiredDf.collect().map(row => row.toSeq.map(_.toString).toSeq).toSeq
```

To use custom column names:

```
scala> val myCols = Seq("myColA", "myColB", "myColC")
myCols: Seq[String] = List(myColA, myColB, myColC)

scala> val requiredDf = tempDf.select((0 until lengthOfRow).map(i => col("value")(i).alias( myCols(i) )): _*)
requiredDf: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [myColA: string, myColB: string ... 1 more field]
```

Comment: Looks good, will try it out before accepting. Just one more thing, if I have all the columns names let say, in a `List[String]` and I want to replace `col1`,`col2` and `col3` with the elements in that list, what do I do?

Comment: updated answer.